# Sliding Door with a tail

Tags: css

I have an `<H2>` with a background that has rounded corners. I'm looking for a way to create a `1px` line that moves from the box to end of the container at the right. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Could you try being a little more specific? A vertical line? That moves from the inside of the H2 to the end?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I finally gave up and stuck some divs in my h2. :(

**CSS**

```
#content h2 {
    background: url(../images/bg-page-title.png) -900px 0px no-repeat;
    font: 1.4em Georgia, Times, Arial bold;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#content h2 .head {
    background: url(../images/bg-page-title.png) no-repeat;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    height: 100%;
}

#content h2 .tail {
    background: url(../images/bg-page-title.png) -857px 0px no-repeat #ffffff;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 15px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h2>
    <div class="head">Find A Job</div>
    <div class="tail">& nbsp;</div>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the line in the background image

Comment: Oh, And the content of the h2 is dynamic in length, but not in height. I can do a background image, but I it would somehow need to be separated from the box.